# SELECT FROM VALUES used a bit like a CASE statement - but possibly more powerful

Tags: t-sql

I just found myself writing the code below - which works.

1. Interesting, but is it necessarily the best method?

the syntax allows the TRY_CAST to only be performed once.
Note "Atextfield" can contain valid numbers and invalid numbers.

```
SELECT * 
FROM call
WHERE
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
        FROM  ( VALUES( TRY_CAST(call.[Atextfield] AS int) )
              ) AS Table1(num)
         WHERE 
               (Table1.num BETWEEN 124 AND 140 )
            OR (Table1.num BETWEEN 143 AND 146 )
            OR (Table1.num BETWEEN 148 AND 149 )
            OR (Table1.num BETWEEN 160 AND 169 )
            OR (Table1.num BETWEEN 181 AND 189 )

      ) 
;
```

2 .Could this be re-written as follows?

```
SELECT *
FROM [call]
WHERE       TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) BETWEEN 124 AND 189
        AND TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) NOT IN (141,142,147)
        AND TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) NOT BETWEEN 150 AND 159
        AND TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) NOT BETWEEN 170 AND 180
```

Note I'm new to CASE in t-sql...

2A.  Is the TRY_CAST(...) evaluated more than once?

3. Which of the above will be quicker?
4. Is there a better way to write this?
5. Is the first method useful when the criteria get more involved and complex.
6. Is this an acceptable approach?

Harvey

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  Sorry the code after question 2 was a bad example. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use exists or 1 = CASE...

Just put your logic in the where clause directly. I'd probably do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [call]
WHERE       TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) BETWEEN 124 AND 189
        AND TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) NOT IN (141,142,147)
        AND TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) NOT BETWEEN 150 AND 159
        AND TRY_CAST([call].AtextField AS TINYINT) NOT BETWEEN 170 AND 180
```

Cross Apply Method:

```
SELECT *
FROM [call]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(PersonID AS TINYINT)) CA(intField)
WHERE       intField BETWEEN 124 AND 189
        AND intField NOT IN (141,142,147)
        AND intField NOT BETWEEN 150 AND 159
        AND intField NOT BETWEEN 170 AND 180
```

My guess is that your query and mine queries will be pretty similiar. If you want to check performance, try running this first and then running each query and recording the logical reads and times.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

Comment: will the TRY_CAST only be evaluated once with this simpler code.?

Comment: I cannot definitively say yes, but I would I bet so. If you are worried it's not so, I can do it with a CROSS APPLY.

Comment: SQL Server is pretty smart so it will probably run both versions the same. It's more for aesthetic purposes if you want to use CROSS APPLY